# How to state "as I had no other choice" adverbially?

Tags: word-request, adverbs, phrases, adverb-placement

I am looking for an adverb which can be substituted for the following phrase defined within double quotation:

- **Example 1)** 
   She said: I was s far away from my apartment and had lost my wallet. I didn't have any cash on me too. He asked me to stay overnight. Even though I couldn't trust him, but **"since / as I had no other choice"** I stayed.
- **Example 2)** 
   I was not into this career. I didn't know anything about cooking. I chose it **"while I had no other choice"**.

Comment: If you do something you don't want to, you do it "reluctantly"

Comment: There's [perforce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perforce) or _of necessity_. (NB Use either _even though_ or _but_, not both. **I didn't trust him, but I had perforce to stay.**)

Comment: *By default* is the most precise way to say #2.  It does not work for #1 because there is a difference in meaning between the two usages.  In example #1 you do have other choices but you have chosen the best option.  You could have slept on the street for example.

Comment: Thank you very much @KateBunting. You properly received my message. Just does the same go for #2? I.e. can I utilize "**perforce**" in the second case in idiomatic English?

Comment: No, I don't think you can use it with _while_. You could say _I chose it out of necessity_.

Comment: Please answer to this question so that I could accept it as the desired response @KateBunting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [perforce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perforce) or *of necessity* for Example 1. (Please note that you need *even though* OR *but,* not both.)

In Example 2, *perforce* doesn't really work, but you could use *of necessity* or *for lack of other options.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no single word that means exactly that.

If you are only given one choice and then asked to choose it, your choice is a *default choice* and you can say you chose it **by default**.  For example - Medical School A only offers Pre-Med as a major.  All new freshman choose Pre-Med as their major *by default.*

If given multiple choices and only one applies to you, your choice will be made *by default*.  For example College A offers two majors Basketball and Pre-Med but to major in Basketball you have to be over two meters tall.  Since I am not over two meters tall my major will be Pre-Med *by default.*

Your sentence #1 is not an example of a default choice since you actually have many choices in that situation, sleeping on the street for example.  You are not choosing a default option.  You are choosing your best option.  *Even though I couldn't trust him, he was still my **safest/best** choice,* is a more precise way to say that.

Keep in mind that *safest* is not a universal way to express *best option*.  It just happens to be the adjective that best applies to this specific sentence/situation.  *Best*, however, will work as a generalized adjective in most *best option* situations.

Comment: How if the subject could not sleep out because of cold or wild animals around etc. @Elleik?

Comment: @A-friend - If I understand what you are asking - You could sleep in the cold or in the tigers' cage.  In that case, however, it may be **best** to sleep at the home of a stranger.